# Autocomplete is getting reset on click of next button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using this [template](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/checkout/) to create a POC where in the very first step i have added an [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) but somehow after selecting the value it is getting reset on click of next button. When i'm clicking on back button to check and change the previously selected value the previously selected value was already gone. Any idea what is going wrong in the below code or needs to be added.

```
 const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

 const handleAutoCompleteChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setSelectedValue(newValue);
    }

 <Autocomplete
                        fullWidth={true}
                        size="small"
                        id="highlights-demo"
                        value={selectedValue}
                        onChange={handleAutoCompleteChange}
                        options={getAllOptions}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField {...params} label="Title" variant="outlined" margin="normal" />
                        )}
                        renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
                            const matches = match(option.title, inputValue);
                            const parts = parse(option.title, matches);
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    {parts.map((part, index) => (
                                        <span key={index} style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}>
                                            {part.text}
                                        </span>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            );
                        }}
                    />
```

Comment: Could you post your full code on something like codesandbox.io - it appears the template doesn't persist the data across next/back clicks either. I think what you're going to need to do is move your state up to a component which displays each page of the form and passes the form values down

Comment: @Matt i'm using Redux to maintain the state across component and i'm fetching the value from the state and passing it to value of Autocomplete still it is not showing the value

Comment: Your posted code shows you using `useState` rather than redux?